# Reading from ifstream multiple times

Tags: c++, load, ifstream

Apologies if this is a really simple question but I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm having trouble with a project I'm working on.

Part of this project involves writing the information of an object to a .txt file and being able to read that .txt file to load in an object. (In this case the information is written rather than the object itself so that someone can easily edit the .txt to change an object).

The function I'm calling to read from the .txt file is as follows:

```
void Room::load(ifstream& inFile)
{
string garbage;
string str;
inFile >> garbage >> garbage >> mId;
inFile >> garbage; getline(inFile, mName);
inFile >> garbage; getline(inFile, mDesc);
loadVec(garbage, inFile, mExits);
}
```

"garbage" being used to get rid of descriptors in the .txt to help a user.

A typical room object should look something like the following:

```
Room ID: 2
Name: Foyer
Description: The player can enter here from the kitchen.
Exits: 3 4
```

My problem occurs when I try to load multiple Rooms. The first Room will load perfectly but any subsequent Room will fail to load properly.

I would have at least expected it to fail in such a way as the first room in the .txt file is loaded repeatedly but that isn't the case.

I'd be very grateful for any help anyone could offer, thanks in advance.

Edit:
For now I'm loading rooms using the following code:

```
if (inFile)
    {
    //Assign data to objects
    room0.load(inFile);
    room1.load(inFile);
    }
```

In this case, room0 winds up with the data of the first room in the .txt file but room1 remains unchanged with the exception of having its exits cleared for some reason.

Testing the program at the moment gives the following:

```
BEFORE LOAD

ID= -1
NAME= Nowhere
DESC= There's nothing here.
Exits= -1

ID= -1
NAME= Nowhere
DESC= There's nothing here.
Exits= -1

AFTER LOAD

ID= 1
NAME=  Kitchen
DESC=  This is the first room the player will see.
Exits= 2 3 5 6

ID= -1
NAME= Nowhere
DESC= There's nothing here.
Exits=

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Those rooms being room0 and room1 respectively both before and after load.

Here's what the loadVec function looks like:

```
//Loads consecutive integers from inFile, saving them to vec
void loadVec(string& garbage, ifstream& inFile, vector<int>& vec)
{
int num;
vec.clear();

inFile >> garbage >> num;
vec.push_back(num);

while (inFile)
{
    inFile >> num;
    vec.push_back(num);
}

vec.erase(vec.begin() + vec.size() - 1);
}
```

And the unedited .txt file from which the program should be loading:

```
Room ID: 1
Name: Kitchen
Description: This is the first room the player will see.
Exits: 2 3 5 6

Room ID: 2
Name: Foyer
Description: The player can enter here from the kitchen, they can exit to the rooms     with the IDs listed as 'Exits'.
Exits: 3 4 

Room ID: 3
Name: Bathroom
Description: This is the third room.
Exits: 4
```

Comment: The code above doesn't appear to load the exits. If that's not the problem then I think you need to show more code. In particular you need to show the *loop* where you try to load more than one room.

Comment: is the information of other rooms also stored in load function? did you tried closing file after writing to it and opening it again for reading?

Comment: Might it be a problem with the `loadVec` function? How are you calling this function? Can you please show some context for how you use it? And ave you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: I've added some more information to the question, I've tried stepping through the load function while watching the "garbage" variable to see what it contains but it remains empty after the first execution.

Comment: Can you also please show the `loadVec` function? And the complete (and unedited) input file?

Comment: The loadVec function and input file have now been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after you have read the exits, the streams `failbit` is set. As long as it's set it will not read anything.

You will have to call [`std::istream::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to clear the error.

---

By the way, there is a more C++-ish way to read into a vector:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(inFile),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(vec));
```

References:

- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

You do of course have to read the "tag" (`garbage`) first before doing this.

Comment: @rbissett You're welcome. :) By the way, you might want to look at my update, there are "better" ways of reading values into a vector.